# How to click link with capybara using xpath with href and data-method

Tags: xpath, capybara

I know how to click link using href and xpath:

`find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/tags/2']").click`

Unfortunately I have 2 links with the same `href`, one has `data-method="delete"` attribute, and I'd like to click this one. How can I change this xpath to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the default css type if you need to:

```
find('a[href="/tags/2"][data-method="delete"]').click
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found an answer:

`find(:xpath, "//a[@href='/tags/2' and @data-method='delete']").click`